# How to pass parameters to ruby command line script

Tags: ruby, command-line, command-line-arguments, heredoc

I pass script to ruby via `STDIN`. E.g.,

```
$ ruby << EE
> puts "args: #{ARGV}"
> EE
args: []
$ ruby << EE
> puts "args: #{ARGV}"
> EE 'arg1' 'arg2'
> EE
-:2: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
EE 'arg1' 'arg2'
    ^
$ ruby 'arg1' 'arg2' << EE
> puts "args: #{ARGV}"
> EE
ruby: No such file or directory -- arg1 (LoadError)
$ ruby -- 'arg1' 'arg2' << EE
> puts "args: #{ARGV}"
> EE
ruby: No such file or directory -- arg1 (LoadError)
$ ruby -e << EE
> puts "args: #{ARGV}"
> EE
ruby: no code specified for -e (RuntimeError)
$
```

I do not know how to pass parameters in this situation. The `-e` option doesn't get what's passed to `STDIN`. According to [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ruby), the syntax is:

```
ruby ... [--] [prog_file] [args]
```

but my `prog_file` is on `STDIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like many other Unix utilities, `ruby` recognizes `-` as a special filename for STDIN:

```
$ echo "p ARGV" | ruby - foo bar
["foo", "bar"]
```

or:

```
$ ruby - foo bar << EE
> p ARGV
> EE
["foo", "bar"]
```

or: (pressing <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to end the input)

```
$ ruby - foo bar
p ARGV
["foo", "bar"]
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @Kashyap I can't find it in the Ruby documentation, but the Pickaxe book mentions it in [Ruby and Its World](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/rubyworld.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can pass parameters like this

```
ruby << EE "" arg1 arg2
> puts ARGV.inspect
> EE
# ["arg1", "arg2"]
```

The `""` is for a ruby file path, or in this case - empty.